# WinCE C++ Application development

Tags: c++, windows-ce

Should I install Windows Embedded CE 6.0 for developing a WinCE application?. 
    What steps should I follow to develop a sample WinCE c++ application? 
    How can I copy the new application to the device?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Should I install Windows Embedded CE
>   6.0 for developing a WinCE application?.

No, you just need Visual Studio 2005/2008 and the SDK of your target device (Visual Studio 2010 does not support WinCE/WinMO development). You may need Windows Embedded CE 6.0 if you are the OEM of the device, depending on your deployment requirements.

> What steps should I follow to develop
>   a sample WinCE c++ application?

Assuming that you are not the OEM of the device, you need to install the SDK, open Visual Studio and follow the template for a new C++ Smart Device Application.

> How can I copy the new application to
>   the device?

If the device has ActiveSync, you can create an installation project in Visual Studio. During development, you can use the deployment options in Visual Studio to copy your application to the device.

Comment: Thanks. What did you mean by the SDK? Where would I get the SDK?

Comment: @Maanu The SDK should be provided to you by the manufacturer (OEM) of your target device. It will integrate to Visual Studio and allow you to use the specific features available for your device.